# Fired or Not Fired

Tags: management, bullying, united-states

Two employees called into boss's office:
"Illinois is an at will state, I can fire you for any reason, I tried to protect you, you snubbed me, now get out of my office."
Employee attempted to say a word and was screamed at to get out of my office.  Assumed we had just been fired and went to HR.  HR said you must have misunderstood..HR called and was told we were not fired.
Went back to work, but now struggling with the treatment and the humiliation of the treatment.  Any advice...both employees had no clue why this had happened to them.  Boss acting like nothing happened.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Advice: Change bosses. Inside the company if you can, outside if necessary. This one is not worth working for.

Comment: File a complaint with HR. I still don't know what the question is, though.

Comment: -1; doesn't actually ask a question.

Answer (score 7):

I presume the question is "what should this employee do about this situation?"

If HR says the employee still has a job, she still has a job.

First of all, this person should keep a log of strange occurrences like this. Make a note of the date and time, who was there, and what was said. She should keep the log with her. Don't give the original to anyone else, only a copy.

Second, this person did the right thing by going to HR for clarification of the situation.

Third, it may (or may not) make sense for the employee to ask for a meeting with the manager who did the yelling. She might begin the conversation by saying something like this:  "I was surprised when you said I snubbed you. I certainly didn't mean to do that, and honestly I wasn't aware of what I did wrong. Can you please help me understand so I won't do it in the future?"  Most managers will respond constructively to this kind of respectful request for feedback.

Fourth, the employee may want to start looking for another job. It's better for her to do that on her own terms rather than after being fired.

Don't forget that it's expensive and time-consuming to recruit and train new employees. It's in the company's interest as well the employee's to continue her employment if that's possible. Managers who torch employees for no reason are damaging their company and probably their own careers.

Comment: If this boss truly did threaten their jobs by saying, "Illinois is an at will state, I can fire you for any reason," then I very much doubt the boss would respond reasonably to a one-on-one meeting.

Comment: True, but this boss is apparently a middle manager in a company with an HR function, so lacks the personal authority to summarily sack somebody.

Answer (score 1):

HR is who ultimately can tell you if you're still an employee.

However, this sounds like an abusive situation, and if these employees are not able to resolve their situation with the boss, I would suggest moving bosses, or  moving companies.

If this behavior is allowed at the company, it's likely to be tolerated elsewhere within the same company.